# Cascading dropdownlist method error 500 in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I am getting the error in dropdownlist as `Method error 500.`

I don't have any idea what wrong with it. I tried various solutions but it didn't work.

Code:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        public static CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetDropDownContentsPageMethod(string knownCategoryValues,string category)
    {
        return new categorylist().GetDropDownContents(knownCategoryValues, category);
    }
```

.aspx:

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Category">Category:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                              <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" 
                                        AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="form-control" style="width:50%;">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                   <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" TargetControlID="DropDownList1"
                                        PromptText="Please select" Category="category1" ServicePath="categorylist.asmx"
                                        ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContents" LoadingText="[Loading sections&#8230;]">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Select Category"
                                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

categorylist.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/categorylist.cs" Class="categorylist" %>
```

categorylist.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml;

/// <summary>
/// Helper web service for CascadingDropDown sample
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
public class categorylist : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    // Member variables
    private static XmlDocument _document;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    // we make these public statics just so we can call them from externally for the
    // page method call
    //
    public static XmlDocument Document
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_document == null)
                {
                    // Read XML data from disk
                    _document = new XmlDocument();
                    _document.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/categorydl.xml"));
                }
            }
            return _document;
        }
    }

    public static string[] Hierarchy
    {
        get
        {

            return new string[] { "category1" };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor to initialize members
    /// </summary>
    public categorylist()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper web service method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="knownCategoryValues">private storage format string</param>
    /// <param name="category">category of DropDownList to populate</param>
    /// <returns>list of content items</returns>
    [WebMethod]
    public AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetDropDownContents(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {
        // Get a dictionary of known category/value pairs
        StringDictionary knownCategoryValuesDictionary = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);

        // Perform a simple query against the data document
        return AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.QuerySimpleCascadingDropDownDocument(Document, Hierarchy, knownCategoryValuesDictionary, category);
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <!--<compilation debug="true"></compilation>-->
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />



      <!--<customErrors mode="Off"/>-->

      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>
      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
      </httpHandlers>

    </system.web>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MSCaptcha" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors>
      <error statusCode="400" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\bad_request.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="401" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\unauthorized.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\forbidden.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\not_found.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="405" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\method_not_allowed.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="406" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\not_acceptable.html"/>
      <error statusCode="407" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\proxy_authentication_required.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="412" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\precondition_failed.html"/>
      <error statusCode="414" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\request-uri_too_long.html"/>
      <error statusCode="415" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\unsupported_media_type.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\internal_server_error.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="501" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\not_implemented.html"/>
      <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="502" path="C:\inetpub\vhosts\dubaiexporters.com\error_docs\bad_gateway.html"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>







</configuration>
```

What causes the error `Method error 500`? I am converting the existing website to responsive website. It is working fine in existing website (framework 3.5). I am converting to responsive website (using framework 4.5.2)? Is that an issue?

Comment: Are you getting unhandled eception? Usually error 500 indicates the code has exception which is unhandled by `catch` block.

Comment: no..i am not getting any exception.i am getting the webform but in dropdownlist it displays Method error 500